# Java Web Application fails to print in Tomcat 7.0.35

Tags: java, tomcat

I have an web application which runs on Tomcat 7.0.35 and my OS is Windows 7. But the application fails to print in this version of Tomcat, where as the print job runs perfectly when the web app is deployed in the standalone version of Tomcat 7.0.55. Is there any solution to print from the web application using Tomcat 7.0.35.

Since my application runs perfectly with Tomcat 7.0.55 standalone version, there is nothing wrong with my code. But the only problem is I need to use Tomcat 7.0.35 version and make the print job run. Is the problem regarded with the Tomcat and windows7?

I am getting the following exception for Tomcat 7.0.35:

```
java.awt.print.PrinterException: Printer is not accepting job.
at sun.print.RasterPrinterJob.print(Unknown Source)
at sun.print.RasterPrinterJob.print(Unknown Source)
at smartq.TokenPrint.printJob(TokenPrint.java:188)
at smartq.rest.api.TokenApi.processToken(TokenApi.java:125)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:699)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2476)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2465)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: please elaborate,what are you trying to print and how?

Comment: Well it's a web service where customers can issue tokens, the token will be printed after clicking print option. But when print option is clicked nothing is printed giving PrinterException.

Comment: If you have an exception and don't understand why you get it, the least you must do is post the stack trace of the exception and the code causing this exception.

Comment: Sorry, but I have added now.

Comment: I very much doubt this has anything to do with the tomcat version. You probably tested on one version and it didn't work for an unrelated reason: network, no paper in the printer or whatever.

Comment: Well the system has been tested by testers. And it has been tested for multiple times and we have tested in tomcat 7.0.35 and tomcat 7.0.55. in tomcat 7.0.55, the application works fine.

Comment: Are both tomcat installation installed on the same machine and for the same user? If not then, the printer may not be configured for one user. It's just an idea.

Comment: Yes, it has been installed and deployed on the same machine. The printer configuration has been checked, it was ok.

Comment: Have you checked JDK version used in both Tomcats?
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8046007

Comment: I have used JDK 6 which is compatible with both the versions.